# How can I store simple hash in perl using data dumper

Tags: perl, data-structures, storage

```
%hash = ('abc' => 123, 'def' => [4,5,6]);
```

how can I store above hash in file using data dumper in Perl

Comment: Try store it as JSON, see e.g. [Cpanel::JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cpanel::JSON::XS). Another alternative is [Storable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Storable)

Answer (score 2):

Files can only contain sequences of bytes, so you need to convert the data structure into a sequence of bytes somehow. This process is called serialization.

The possibilities available to you are endless, but a few are worth mentioning:

- JSON is a very common choice.
- YAML is more flexible.
- [Storable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Storable) is specifically made for Perl data structures.

There is also Data::Dumper, as you say.

```perl
use Data::Dumper qw( );

sub serialize {
   my ($x) = @_;
   local $Data::Dumper::Purity = 1;    # Required for some data structures.
   local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;     # Optional. Limits output to ASCII.
   local $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;  # Optional. Makes revision control easier.
   return Data::Dumper->Dump([$x], ["x"]);
}

print($fh serialize($x));
```

Data::Dumper isn't a particularly good choice, since there's no existing module to safely deserialize the structure in Perl<sup>[1]</sup>, and there's even less support outside of Perl.

```perl
sub deserialize {
   my ($s) = @_;
   my $x;
   eval($s);       # XXX Unsafe!
   die($@) if $@;
   return $x;
}
```

---

1. If you're ok with limiting yourself to data structure JSON can serialize (by setting `Purity` to `0`), then you could use [Data::Undump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Undump) to safely deserialize. But then why not just use JSON?!

Comment: Answer didn't originally answer the question. Fixed.

Comment: what is purity = 1 and why ["x"] in the statement return Data::Dumper->Dump([$x], ["x"]);

Comment: Read the docs and try it out. Especially with `[$r,$r]` where `my $r=[];`.

Answer (score 0):

```pl
use Data::Dumper

open (FL, ">", "file.txt") or die "Cant open file $! ";
print FL Dumper \%hash;
close FL;
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. You should give a short statement, what your code do. (e.g. "write the output of the dumper to a file")

Answer (score -1):

*"how can I store above hash in file using data dumper in Perl"*

Store it as JSON so it can be read back by (almost) anything, using `Data::Dumper` configured to print JSON.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

local $Data::Dumper::Pair = ' : ';
local $Data::Dumper::Quotekeys = 1;
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
local $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;

my %hash = ('abc' => 123, 'def' => [4,5,6]);

open my $file, '>', 'foo.json' or die $!;

print $file Dumper \%hash;
```

Output:

```
$ cat foo.json
{
  "def" : [
             4,
             5,
             6
           ],
  "abc" : 123
}
```

(Note: I would of course rather use a dedicated JSON-handling module for this, but you asked ....)

Comment: Tq but can you please explain what is quotekeys and Terse in above code

Comment: That doesn't produce valid JSON for even simple data like anything that contains my name.